# Use username media endpoint without Authentication Instagram API

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Recently i found this endpoint https://www.instagram.com/{username}/?__a=1 that not requiers authentication for use.

I need to know if may use this endpoint for integrate in an mobile application. 
The endpoint is not listed on instagram documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But i dont understand. It's not possible to get instagram profile media data in anyway without authentication? I hate this.

tearing me apart.

Answer (score 0):

Not a good idea to use it in a production app, API is undocumented and may stop working anytime, there was another undocumented API that a lot of people were using for few years in apps and it stopped working 3 weeks ago without any warning.

Comment: Thanks.. i wanted to use this endpoint but i think is a bad idea too.